# Cannot access index of array pointer C

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to set up an adjacent list array in C:

```
mygraph->table = (Node *)malloc(MaxSize * sizeof(Node));
check(mygraph->table, error);
int i;
for(i = 1; i <= MaxSize; i++)
{
    mygraph->table[i].name = NULL;
    mygraph->table[i].outlist = NULL;
    mygraph->table[i].outdegree = 0;
}
...
```

When I run this code, it works fine. But when I try to access an index in the table I get a segmentation fault:

```
mygraph->table[n].name = name;
```

I checked the `n` index, and it is correct. `MaxSize` is 10, but I get a segmentation fault even when `n` = 1.

EDIT:

```
typedef struct linkedlist { // linked list of ints (for use in Node)
  int index;
  struct linkedlist *next;
} List;

typedef struct { // a Node of a Graph
  char *name;
  List *outlist; // adjacency list
  int outdegree; // length of outlist
  //double pagerank_score; //not needed for this exercise
} Node;

typedef struct {
  // your code goes here
  int MaxSize;      /*Maximum number of vertices that the graph can constain*/
  Node *table;     /*Adjacency lists' array*/
} Graph;
```

Comment: did you allocate memory for `name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the key:

```
mygraph->table[n].name = name;
```

There is no mention of allocating memory for the `name` variable.

Also, assigning `name` variable on the right hand side of expression, it would be better to indicate, by using `strncpy` or `strdup` to state your intention.

The onus is on you to ensure you do indeed, `free` the memory occupied by the `name` member also.

Comment: If the name variable on the right was allocated properly, the assignment should be valid, but indeed, if the original pointer gets deallocated somewhere else later, then there is a problem.

Comment: Indeed, it is valid, but to the discerning eye, what is `name`, where did it come from? Cue looking around elsewhere, it would be easier if it had the intention of indicating that it was `strcpy` or `strdup` , which clues in more in 'a-ha, its a pointer variable'. :)

Comment: I tried using strcpy(mygraph->table[n].name, name); but it still fails

Answer (score 2):

> I get a segmentation fault even when `n = 1`.

This is because your code has undefined behavior. It writes past the end of the array:

```
for(i = 1; i <= MaxSize; i++) // should be i=0 ; i<MaxSize
```

When `n` is `10` the code does not crash on your system - perhaps because `malloc` adds enough padding at the end of the block to accommodate an extra element past the end of the array, but the error is still there.

You can find such hidden errors using a memory profiler, e.g. [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).

The fix is to use correct indexes in the initialization:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i != MaxSize ; i++) {
}
```

Comment: It crashes for every number, even 10

Comment: I tried your fix but it still crashes... I'll post the declaration of Node and Graph

Comment: @Alessandro It's probably crashes in some other place now, because this is the error in the code that you have posted.

Comment: There's not much I do really, just initialise and try to change one index.

Comment: @Alessandro You may want to post the "try to change one index" code, too.

Comment: @dasbilnkenlight its just a method with one line of code: mygraph->table[n].name = name;

Comment: @Alessandro Is the value of `n` in `mygraph->table[n].name` strictly less than the number of nodes that you allocated?

Comment: @dasbilnkenlight yes it is, I printed and checked

Answer (score 1):

Your loop need to run from `0` to `MaxSize-1`, like this:

```
for(i = 0; i < MaxSize; i++)
{
    mygraph->table[i].name = NULL;
    mygraph->table[i].outlist = NULL;
    mygraph->table[i].outdegree = 0;
}
```

so the first element will be at `mygraph->table[0]` and the last element will be at
 `mygraph->table[MaxSize-1]`.

In pointer arithmetic, the first element will start at `mygraph->table` and the last element will **start** at:

```
((mygraph->table) + MaxSize-1)
```

and would **end** at:

```
((mygraph->table) + MaxSize)
```

`table[MaxSize]` is equivalent `*((mygraph->table) + MaxSize)` and this is out of the array boundaries.